# associativity of composition

Tags: category-theory

Perhaps a bit silly, but I can't find a really convincing answer: why is associativity of composition so fundamental that it's included in the axioms for a category?

I suppose that the lack of structure would mean that it's hard to build an interesting theory, but perhaps there's a nice example to drive the point home?

Answer (score 2):

The motivating example for categories is sets with structure and structure-preserving functions between them. Composition of functions is associative.